# How do I resove this issue on cPanel, for a laravel project? I get the error when I try to navigate to Login page

Tags: laravel, cpanel, npm-install

Missing Mix Manifest File

The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /home/****/public_html/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php)

Did you forget to run npm install && npm run dev?

Comment: Laravel requires a `mix-manifest.json` file that is generated in the public folder which maps the minified files to the actual source code files. This is only generated once you run `npm install && npm run production`. I think you probably forgot to run this command after deploying your code. Please check your public folder for a `mix-manifest.json` file.

Comment: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix) is a detailed explanation, you might wanna have a look at.

Comment: @Salvino Thank you very much, I had moved the file together with the "index" file out of the "public" folder. I moved it back after you mentioned it, and everything is good now.